# Rails pass value/object/orm from parent controller to child

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

To keep to restfull protocol, I need to do `/api/backup_jobs/777/errors`.

In rails, the parent controller- I have:

```
module Api
  class BackupJobsController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :json

    def show
      @backup_job = @backup_jobs.find(params[:id])
      respond_with data: @backup_job
    end
  end
end
```

---

in the child controller:

```
module Api
  class ErrorsController < BackupJobsController
    respond_to :json

    def index
      respond_with data: @backup_jobs.find(params[:id]).backup_events.errors
    end
  end
end
```

But obvisouley this isn't going to work because `params[]` doesn't exist for `/api/backup_jobs/777/errors`

1. How can I pass the `@backup_job = @backup_jobs.find(params[:id])` from the parent controller's `def show` to the child controller and have it accessible in the child's `def index`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that because when an ErrorsController is created and used, you will not have a BackupsJobsController that ran before it.

This comes down to the nature of HTTP being a request-response protocol.

Instead, you can extract the line of code you wrote into a method that will be inherited by the ErrorsController.

**backup_jobs_controller.rb**:

```
module Api 
  class BackupJobsController < ApplicationController
    def show
      find_backup_job
      respond_with data: @backup_job
    end

  protected

    def find_backup_job
      @backup_job = @backup_jobs.find(params[:id])
      # or maybe @backup_job = BackupJob.find(params[:id])
    end

  end
end
```

**errors_controller.rb**:

```
module Api
  class ErrorsController < BackupJobsController
    respond_to :json

    def index
      respond_with data: find_backup_job.backup_events.errors
    end
  protected

    def find_backup_job
      @backup_job = BackupJob.find(params[:backup_job_id])
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: how would I tell it what job to find if `errors` controller has no param? remember the url is `/api/backup_jobs/777/errors`